# how to get a element index number using element of an array in JavaScript

Tags: arrays, indexing, element, indexof

let's assume this is my array

```
 `const arr=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`
```

How can i get the index number of 'e'

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Read the Array API documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: `indexof` is literally one of the tags on your question heh

Comment: The owner changed the question to a completely different question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
const array = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges"];
const orangesIndex = array.indexOf("oranges");
console.log(orangesIndex) // 2
console.log(array[orangesIndex]) // "oranges"
```